# python excel synchronization

Tags: python, excel

Would just like to know what would be the best way to synchronize python and excel. Meaning: Python script would be running and excel sheet open. Excel would read values from python and python would read values from excel. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: probably a better question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) and I would say it would have to involve some sort of database like sql or something.. I'm not sure how to do that on the excel end of things

Comment: you definitely can't just open a regular file in both excel and edit it at the same time with `openpyxl`

Answer (score 0):

[xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) allows you to interact with an open Excel workbook using Python. It also allows you to call Python code from within Excel macros.