# How can i write on an XLS file using python?

Tags: python, sharepoint, xls

I want to open a .xls file on python modify some rows and rewrite the new content on the same file because i use a macro to synchronise the data with SharePoint.
What libraries can i use?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using pandas with :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('path/file.xls')
# modifications here ....
df.to_excel('path/file.xls')
```

Comment: This method wont keep my macro and connection to sharepoint inside the original file

Comment: So I think you could go there if I am right with xlwings : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848131/python-excel-synchronization

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `openpyxl`?
It's very easy to modify xlsx file using this library.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned/updated directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Python types will automatically be converted
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

For more details you can refer to the [openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html).

Comment: My original file is .xls and not .xlsx. The problem i am facing is that the macro that i have do not work on a .xlsx file or else i would have changed the file type and used this method